# ¿Cómo puedo anidar condiciones en R?

Tags: r, condiciones, grep

Tengo un df muy grande que más o menos se ve así (en versión reducida):

```
df1
df1 <- data.frame("ID" = c("125863889IP02","597586217EX000552","KKFR256987412593", "TR74325987412368","ML84563259856324), hijos = c("FR22", "0000", "0000", "FT45","000"), nietos = c("TM42", "0000", "PM26", "0000", "0000"), año = c("1992", "1998", "2001", "2006", "2010")
```

Tengo que hacer varias estructuras de control, pero no tengo idea de cómo escribirlas, no sé cómo digitar las órdenes.

Por un lado lo que quiero es separar los ID's de acuerdo a que contengan ciertos caracteres. Creo que sería algo así:

```
if(grep("FR|IP|EX000552", df1$ID, value=T)){
  GRU="GRUP1"
  }else{
    GRU="GRUP2"
  }

#Es decir, todos los Ids que contengan FR|IP|EX000552 deben estar en GRUP1.
```

Por otro, debo agruparlos de acuerdo a si tienen hijos o no y de acuerdo al año, y escribir un fichero final.

```
if(año<=1992,(df$año), & hijos="0000"(df1$hijos) or nietos="0000",(df1$nietos){
  cap="P92"
  padre=GRU+cap #Aquí que me ponga el grupo al que pertenece seguido de cap
write(ID, padre, hijos, cap) #Que escriba un fichero final
```

¿Cómo debo hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Aclaración

entiendo que lo que quieres es adosar dos columnas a `df1`

- una que indique el grupo cuando se cumple la condición del regex
- otra que indique el "cap" cuando se cumplen las otras condiciones.

Luego escribir ese resultado en una unidad de almacenamiento.

Hay varias formas de hacerlo. Si tus condiciones siempre van a producir clasificaciones binarias (i.e. dos grupos, uno cuando se cumple la condición, otro cuando no) la función `ifelse()` tiene una sintaxis muy clara con tres
argumentos: la condición, un valor cuando esa condición regresa `TRUE` y otro valor cuando regresa `FALSE`. Al menos por el ejemplo que nos estás presentando parece que es lo que necesitas, aunque las cosas podrían complicarse si vamos a evaluar más de una condición y generar más de dos grupos. No sería imposible, pero sí más complicado.

## Operadores lógicos en R

Para establecer la condición vale la pena un repaso de los operadores lógicos en R. `==` es igual a. `&` significa **y**, es decir, se tienen que cumplir ambas condiciones conectadas por este operador. `|` significa **o**, es decir, regresa `TRUE` cuando se cumplen cualquiera de las dos condiciones.

## Solución

La primera parte de `ifelse()` debe producir un vector lógico (de valores `TRUE` o `FALSE`) del mismo largo que el vector que queremos crear. Por eso vamos a usar `grepl` en lugar de `grep`. `grepl` es `grep` lógico, en lugar de regresarnos los valores o las posiciones que hacen match en el regex nos va a regresar un vector lógico con `TRUE` cuando hay match y `FALSE` cuando no lo hay. Es lo que necesitamos para `ifelse()`

Vamos a crear dos columnas nuevas en `df1`, una llamada `GRU` y otra llamada `cap`. Parto de tu ejemplo reproducible y lo hago de la manera más simple, usando `<-`.

```
df1$GRU <- ifelse(grepl("FR|IP|EX000552", df1$ID), "GRUP1", "GRUP2")
df1$cap <- ifelse(as.numeric(df1$año) <= 1992 & df1$hijos == "0000"| df1$nietos == "0000",   #Uso as.numeric porque en el df1 año es character y <= sólo se puede aplicar a numeric
                  "P92",                                                                     #Valor cuando se cumplen todas las condiciones
                  "no_es_P92")                                                               #Valor cuando no se cumplen
df1
                 ID hijos nietos  año   GRU       cap
1     125863889IP02  FR22   TM42 1992 GRUP1 no_es_P92
2 597586217EX000552  0000   0000 1998 GRUP1       P92
3  KKFR256987412593  0000   PM26 2001 GRUP1       P92
4  TR74325987412368  FT45   0000 2006 GRUP2       P92
5  ML84563259856324   000   0000 2010 GRUP2       P92
```

Con esto ya tienes el `data.frame` completo. Quizás tengas bueno motivos para guardarlo con `write`. Sin embargo, a menos que el procesamiento se demore muchísimo, lo mejor es no guardar la estructura de datos y guardar, en cambio, el código que la produce. Si necesitas guardalo para compartirlo o por el motivo que sea te sugeriría guardarlo con un archivo de valores separados por comas. Mira `help("write.csv")` par ver como hacerlo. La ventaja es los `.csv` son un formato estándar que cualquiera puede abrir con una planilla de cálculos, editor de textos, etc.  Si no te interesa conservar todas las columnas en el resultado final haces primero un subset de las columnas que te interesan y luego guardas ese resultado.

Espero que te ayude, si no comprendí bien la pregunta dímelo.